# Can't get header request Rails 5 API on production stage (AWS elasticbeanstalk)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have rails 5 API. Tested on my local it running perfect. But after deploy to elastic beanstalk I have problem, I can't getting Authentication token which I put it on header, and this is how I set token when call API and get/ read on my app :

Set when call api :

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST http://example.com/users -H "Authorization: eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGc"
```

And Read/ get :

```
auth_header = request.headers['Authorization'] and token = auth_header.split(' ').last
```

Any ideas what's going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I resolved by using dash("-") instead of underscore("_") in the
>   header.

```
 example:
```

> ```
>     authentication-token
>
>     instead of
>
>     authentication_token
>
>
>     It will work 100%
> ```

Comment: Super... Thanks Jigar